# Assign a variable and check value?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible somethings like this:

```
var userAggregazione;
if (userAggregazione = YouTube.Actions.IsAccessTokenValid() != null)
{
}
```

`IsAccessTokenValid()` returns a `userAggregazione` instance or `null`. So, inside the if, I'd like to setup `var userAggregazione`, and check if it is `null` or not.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think, it's not possible. Compiler will warn you.

Comment: You can't have left hand `var` variable without being able to infer a type on the left hand. `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized` Why not simply assign the variable like normal THEN check for null? What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: `without being able to infer a type on the left hand` i meant "right hand" here of course ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if there's an extra parentheses around the assignment, so that it will get evaluated before the `!=` comparison.

```
MyClass userAggregazione;
if ((userAggregazione = YouTube.Actions.IsAccessTokenValid()) != null)
{}
```

edit2:
I assume the example is simplified, because normally you should do like this for clarity:

```
//my style preference is also to not use 'var' anyway
//when getting value from a function
//because it's not clear what the type is.
MyClass userAggregazione = YouTube.Actions.IsAccessTokenValid();
if (userAggregazione != null)
{}
```

Comment: This has a syntax error: `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized`

Answer (score 3):

not sure if I understand but let me attempt:

```
var userAggregazione = YouTube.Actions.IsAccessTokenValid();
if (userAggregazione == null)
{
   // userAggregazione is null - do something
}
else
{
   // it is not null - do something
}
```

Comment: This is what you want to do.  While the assignment operator in c# does indeed return a value which you can then test against, it's much clearer to simply assign the result to a variable, and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you need to add some braces:

```
if ((userAggregazione = YouTube.Actions.IsAccessTokenValid()) != null)
```

Just ensure that `IsAccessTokeValid` does not throw any exceptions